# Stop Code in C++

Tags: c++

How do you stop the code from running in C++? I have the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int total, sub, subc;
    cout << "What number would you like to start with? ";
    cin >> total;
        cout << "Enter in a number, 1 or 2, to subtract";
    cin >> sub;
    if (sub == 1) {
        total--;
        subc++;
        cout << "You subtracted one";
    }
    else {
        total = total - 2;
        subc++;
    }
    if (sub <= 0)
        cout << "YAY!";
}
```

and i want to insert a thing that just stops the code and exits right after `cout << "YAY!"`
how do i do that???

Comment: It already does?

Comment: ... like by changing that to `if (sub <= 0) { cout << "YAY!"; return 0; }` (assuming you'd change the rest of the code to run in a loop first)? :)

Comment: Would it be asking to much that you learn the basics of C++ control flow and then revisit your problem? There are no loops in your program and no recursion, so it is inevitable that your program terminates eventually.

Comment: Edited quested to be more clear. I'm pretty sure Solomon meant to pause the program before it exits. Replaced "stop" with "pause".

Comment: Emile: Are you sure? (It's certainly possible...) Solomon?

Comment: Rolled back edits in light of the chosen answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A return statement will end the `main` function and therefore the program:

```
return 0;
```

ETA: Though as @Mysticial notes, this program will indeed end right after the `cout << "YAY!"` line.

ETA: If you are in fact working within a while loop, the best way to leave the loop would be to use a `break` statement:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int total, sub, subc;
    cout << "What number would you like to start with? ";
    cin >> total;
    while (1) {
            cout << "Enter in a number, 1 or 2, to subtract";
        cin >> sub;
        if (sub == 1) {
            total--;
            subc++;
            cout << "You subtracted one";
        }
        else {
            total = total - 2;
            subc++;
        }
        if (sub <= 0) {
            cout << "YAY!";
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I get the feeling there's a while loop yet to be written.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
 char c;
 cin >> c;
```

This will wait until you hit enter before exiting.

or you can do:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
system("pause");
```

Answer (score 0):

As David Robinson already noted, your example makes no sense, since the program will stop anyway after

> cout << "YAY!";

But depending on the scenario, besides *break* and *return*, also *exit()* might help. 
See the manpage:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/exit/